# Query category name by variable

Tags: php

I have this part of code and I want to replace `name-category` in the query part with my variable `$nisola`. How it is the right code thanks

```
<?php $nisola = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'isola', true); ?>
<?php
$post_categoria = new WP_Query('category_name=name-category');
while($post_categoria->have_posts()) : $post_categoria->the_post();
```

Comment: I wonder about the context in which this code sequence is intended to work, since on its face it seems kind of backwards and redundant - in an attempt to emulate the function of a category or other taxonomy in some version of a new query within a query...

Comment: thanks guys but if i want add this filter code `.'posts_per_page' => how do it become

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/113228)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you miss some PHP basics? http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Anyhow,

This

```
$post_categoria = new WP_Query('category_name=name-category');
```

Should become this:

```
$post_categoria = new WP_Query('category_name=' . $nisola);
```

Comment: Or simply `new WP_Query( [ 'category_name' => $nisola ] );` https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

Comment: thanks guys but if i want add this filter code .'posts_per_page' => how do it become